# Complex GEF4 Zest example - Print to PDF - Edge connects multiple nodes

Tags: eclipse-gef, zest

I am writing code in GEF4/Zest to represent train runs (connections) from stations to stations (nodes), as depicted in the attached image. This image is built with GEF4, but my needs are a little more, as below, that I am still looking for the solution.
[image]

1. We need to draw the train run X, the only manual drawn thick black line, to connect Station1 to Station2 but via Station3 (train makes a stop at this station), currently an edge/connection is only made by 2 nodes, is that possible to have a "via node" for an edge/connection in GEF4/Zest?
2. Is there any snippet GEF4 code to print the whole view (including the invisible zones due to zoom) to PDF? (printing to image is already OK).

Thanks in advance for your suggestions/helps!

Cheers
Dan

Comment: Please refer to the corresponding thread in the GEF forum to join the discussion: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1087142/

Comment: Hey @Duvu how did you make several inputs (apparently with different names) for each block? Can you by any chance share your code?